# Miktex on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, crash, miktex

I have some problems with Miktex installed on Windows Vista Business SP1/32 bit. I use miktex 2.7, ghostscript, and texniccenter 1 beta 7.50. When I compile a document with the following profiles: Latex=>DVI, Latex=>PDF everything works fine; the system crashes when I compile with profiles Latex=>PS and Latex=>PS=>PDF. The error is reported into a window that states: "Dvi-to-Postscript converter has stopped working". What can I do? I need Latex=>PS=>PDF to include my images into the final PDF.

Thanks in advance,
Yet another LaTeX user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything you need is images, you could still compile directly to PDF. You only need to have an image in PNG or JPG format, and use the following code:

```
%in the document preamble
\usepackage{graphicx}

%in the document, in the place where you want to put your image
\includegraphics{image_filename_without_extension}
```

When the image is a PNG or JPG file (there are some more, I don't remember which ones ATM), you can compile the file with pdfLaTeX, but not with the normal LaTeX (i.e. you can produce a PDF, but not DVI or PS).
Of course normally, if everything works fine, it's nice to have one copy of the image in EPS, and another in, say, PNG -- this way you can compile easily both to PDF, and to PS.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. I have solved the problem: the dvi crashed because I have installed Miktex with the User Account Control enabled. I have disabled it, reinstalled and now it's working (with UAC still disabled).